# Wheel event triggers many times react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-hooks, mousewheel

I'm trying to realize full page scroll. My problem is wheel event often triggers twice.
I realized it on vanilla js and it works nicely.

```
const [ index, setIndex ] = useState(0);
const sectionWrapper = useRef();
const animationBreak = 750;
const maxIndex = 2;
let lastTime = 0;

useEffect(
    () => {
        const handleWheel = e => {
            const sections = sectionWrapper.current.children;
            const wheelDirection = e.wheelDelta;
            const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            const isAnimationEnable = currentTime - lastTime > animationBreak;

            if (!isAnimationEnable) return;

            if (wheelDirection < 0 && index < maxIndex) {
                setIndex(index + 1);
            }

            if (wheelDirection > 0 && index > 0) {
                setIndex(index - 1);
            }

            sections[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
            lastTime = currentTime;
        };

        window.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);

        return () => window.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
    },
    [ index ]
);
```

I tryied to use lodash's methods like throttle or debounce. Not works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove / reassign the event handler each time the index changes, the event handling code never changes, you just need access to the most recent `index` state. You can do this by using a callback on the `setX` function e.g.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleWheel = e => {
    const sections = sectionWrapper.current.children;
    const wheelDirection = e.wheelDelta;
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const isAnimationEnable = currentTime - lastTime > animationBreak;

    if (!isAnimationEnable) return;

    let index;
    setIndex(i => index = i); // read most recent index
    // use a temp var to get the new state value for scrolling later
    let newIndex;
    if (wheelDirection < 0 && index < maxIndex) {
      setIndex(i => (newIndex = ++i)); // increment the current index by 1
    }

    if (wheelDirection > 0 && index > 0) {
      setIndex(i => (newIndex = --i)); // decrement the current index by 1
    }

    sections[newIndex].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    lastTime = currentTime;
  };

  window.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
}, []); // we no longer need any dependences here
```

Comment: I think it's tricky about access to index state using variable. Why is that? Why we can't access directly to index state?

Comment: Now I have a problem with conditions `index < maxIndex` and `index > 0`. If index is variable it always be undefined. if index is state it always be  0.

Comment: @nukuutos oh sorry, my local var will be clashing names with the state var - let me update

Comment: I understood you last time. It's not working correct. I want to deal with var. Again: "it's tricky about access to index state using variable. Why is that? Why we can't access directly to index state?"

Comment: @nukuutos I can see why it won't be currently working correctly, the `handleWheel` handler is created once inside `useEffect` and then never re-created, meaning the state logic never changes. Let me update to fix

Comment: It works(only we should do `--i` instead `i--`)!  I can't understand one thing. Why do we use variable and can't access directly a state?

Comment: @nukuutos sorry, yeah, that was a mistake, it should be `--i` like the `++i` as we want the value to be updated before it's assigned, that's a typo (will update). I'm using a local var so I can read the current state because we no longer invalidate `useEffect` therefore if we refer to the state directly, given its a closure at this point, we only ever store the first state.

Answer (score 0):

useRef solves this problem more cleaner way.

```
    const [ index, setIndex ] = useState(0);
    // using useRef to ref to index
    const indexRef = useRef();
    indexRef.current = index;

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleWheel = e => {
            const sections = sectionWrapper.current.children;
            const wheelDirection = e.wheelDelta;
            const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            const isAnimationEnable = currentTime - lastTime > animationBreak;

            if (!isAnimationEnable) return;

            if (wheelDirection < 0 && indexRef.current < maxIndex) {
                setIndex(() => indexRef.current + 1);
                sections[indexRef.current].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
            }

            if (wheelDirection > 0 && indexRef.current > 0) {
                setIndex(() => indexRef.current - 1); 
                sections[indexRef.current].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
            }

            lastTime = currentTime;
        };

        window.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);

        return () => window.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
    }, []);
```